# Objective C: Filtering Core Data Information based on Set of Annotations visible in current MapRect

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

I have around 1000+ core data objects for my application. The application consist of a mapView and a tableView.

I am interested in displaying only the annotations that are appearing in the current mapRect. Hence I am using the method

```
NSSet *nearbySet = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:self.mapView.visibleMapRect];
```

The above method will return me a set of annotations available in the current mapView.

Now I only want to display the information based on the annotations returned from the above method in the table view (CoreData Table). How can I query core data for this? Can I use the predicate method with the NSFetchResultController? Any advice on this will be greatly appreicated!

Zhen Hoe

EDIT (10.05.2011):
My location data model is as such:

```
@dynamic uniqueID;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic address;
@dynamic longitude;
@dynamic latitude;
```

I have implemented the CoreDataTableViewController as shown below:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) 
    {
        if (self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate != normalPredicate) 
        {
            [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:self.fetchedResultsController.cacheName];
            self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = normalPredicate;
            [self performFetchForTableView:tableView];
        }
        [currentSearchText release];
        currentSearchText = nil;
    } 
}
```

I was thinking of modifying the line 'self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = normalPredicate" to restrict the fetch to only the objects found in my nearbySet. Is this a good place to do it? Also if you can give me some tips on how to write the predicate part, that will be great!

Thanks

Zhen Hoe

Comment: How do you store and identify an annotation in core-data?

Comment: @Nick, I was thinking of querying the core data based on the set of annotations I received from the method. For example, the method returned me 2 annotations, can I use something like request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", nearbySet valueForKey:"title"]; I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Also, how do I check that the name of my annotation is the same as the one in core data?

Comment: I think one of the problems we face here is: how to tell if a place unique described by an annotation. We've got the coordinate, subtitle and title. You can easily store them but how to retrieve and match after coming back with new annotations. I was thinking about hashing the coordinates and the title. A problem may be if google localizes titles.

Comment: The details of the predicate will depend on the details of your data model. We'll need more such details to really advise.

Comment: @TechZen, thanks for response :) I have updated my initial question with some information. Is that sufficient? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Zhen: I think you would want `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@", nearbySet valueForKey:"title"];` instead.